# Where do I get an annotation file for yeast genome with ENSEMBL ids?

Tags: database, yeast, gene-annotation

Even the annotation files hosted on  the [Ensembl site](ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/fungi/release-40/gff3/saccharomyces_cerevisiae) have systematic names (starting with Y..) instead of ENSEMBL ids (starting with EN..).

I bet there would be a place where I can get an annotation file (GFF3 preferably). Please let me know if you know such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a further search for the answer, I realised that unconventionally, ENSEMBL ids for yeast start with Y. That is strange. I guess this is because the yeast annotations are primarily maintained by SGD (yeast genome database) and ENSEMBL just hosts a copy of that.

Also these ids are called *Stable Gene IDs*.